# A high-rank version of Travelling salesman

Tags: algorithm, optimization

A traveling salesman problem can be formalized as follows: finding a circular ordering C of n city：C=[c(1),c(2),...,c(n)],in which c(i) are non-replicative numbers from 1 to n.

the objective function is (we adapt the notation c(n+i)=c(i))

Σd(c(i),c(i+1))

In my case I have a non negative function like q(i,j,k,l) plays the role of distances. I'm looking forward to minimize this:

Σq(c(i),c(j),c(i+1),c(j+1))

there are some extra properties might help, like q(i,j,i,k)=0, and q(i,j,k,l)=q(j,i,k,l)=q(k,l,i,j)

This is complicated than TSP so must be NP-complete, I'm looking for a working metaheuristic method but seems genetic algorithm do not work very well and ant colony method can't adapted to this problem naively, has this problem been researched?

Comment: You might want to post this on [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: There are some approximation algorithm to "solve" this TSP problem. The length of paths these algorithm find is at most 2*(length of optimal path). By using some heuristic skills, the rate can be reduced to 3/2 the length of optimal path

Comment: I'd be curious to see an example of function `q` with an explanation of how it relates to some real world constraint.

Comment: @user3386109 It's from a biological problem and for now I can't say two much about that. You might love to take a look at http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702515